# find the domain of this function ( [ ] is symbol of floor)

Tags: euclidean-domain

Find the domain of the function $f(x)=\frac{\log(3x-2x^2)}{\left \lfloor 2x-1 \right \rfloor^2 - 1}$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the [floor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html).

Comment: For future reference, you can use MathJax to render maths on this site. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial

Comment: The symbol of floor is $\lfloor\:\rfloor$. See : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118173/how-to-write-ceil-and-floor-in-latex

Answer (score 0):

The domain is$$D=\{x\in\Bbb R\quad,\quad 3x-2x^2>0,[(2x-1)^2]\ne1\}=\{x\in\Bbb R\quad,\quad 0<x<\dfrac{3}{2},[(2x-1)^2]\ne1\}=(0,1)\cup[\dfrac{1+\sqrt 2}{2},\dfrac{3}{2})$$